# Why there isn't vim plugin for c++ code navigation based on syntax

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, ctags

Vim has many good completion plugin such as omnicppcompletion or youcompleteme. But what are some plugin for navigation? why cannot they use the code in completion plugin to detect what class a instance belong to and navigate to the definition of that instance class's method.
Using the plain ctag is a pain that it cannot detect the instance class so it give me countless number of methods belongs to different class when I use g-] to go to definition. I want it to detect the class of the instance. Is there any can do it?

Comment: Vim is a text editor, not a code editor. I've been using Vim for many years but I prefer an IDE for editing code, to get things like true intellisense and good jump to definition.

Comment: @AndyRay The thing is that there is already such feature in vim completion. So it will just be easy to move that feature of syntax detecting to code navigation in vim. But it seems no one realizes this.

Comment: If you want it and it doesn't exist, write it.